# Reading a csv file in html format "ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 103, saw 2"

Tags: python, pandas

There is a csv [file](https://github.com/arthursdays/HKBU_HPML_COVID-19/blob/master/preprocessing/ccccii/CT_cleaned_v2.csv) in github that the developer reads using read_csv function like this:

```
import pandas as pd
ref = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv').fillna(0)

for _, line in ref.iterrows():
    #print(line)
    pid = line['pid']
    cls = line.cls
    scan_id = line.scan_id
    is_seg = line.is_seg
```

I'm attempting to do the same thing, but I'm obtaining the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 103, saw 2
```

I believe the reason is that when I opened the file in Visual Studio Code, it was in html format.

The header of the file:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" data-color-mode="auto" data-light-theme="light" data-dark-theme="dark">
      <head>
    <div class="markdown-body">
        <table class="js-csv-data csv-data js-file-line-container">
          <thead>
            <tr id="LC1" class="js-file-line">
              <td id="L1" class="blob-num js-line-number" data-line-number="1"></td>
                <th>cls</th>
                <th>pid</th>
                <th>scan_id</th>
                <th>is_seg</th>
                <th>is_repeat</th>
                <th>repeat_ids</th>
                <th>re_order</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
    </div>
```

What is the proper method for reading such files?

Comment: It’s not a traditional CSV file format, that’s for sure. Why not try reading it as a html table https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a traditional CSV file format, that’s for sure. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Why not try reading it as a html table https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: I have read it by pd.read_html then convert html tables to csv